# Data aggregation by week or by 3 days

Tags: r, subset, stat

Here is an example of my data:

```
 Date        Prec       aggregated by week (output)

        1/1/1950    3.11E+00    4.08E+00

        1/2/1950    3.25E+00    9.64E+00

        1/3/1950    4.81E+00    1.15E+01

        1/4/1950    7.07E+00    

        1/5/1950    4.25E+00    

        1/6/1950    3.11E+00    

        1/7/1950    2.97E+00    

        1/8/1950    2.83E+00    

        1/9/1950    2.72E+00    

        1/10/1950   2.72E+00    

        1/11/1950   2.60E+00    

        1/12/1950   2.83E+00    

        1/13/1950   1.70E+01    

        1/14/1950   3.68E+01    

        1/15/1950   4.24E+01    

        1/16/1950   1.70E+01    

        1/17/1950   7.07E+00    

        1/18/1950   3.96E+00    

        1/19/1950   3.54E+00    

        1/20/1950   3.40E+00    

        1/21/1950   3.25E+00
```

I have long time series precipitation data and I want to aggregate it in such a way that (output is in third column; I calculated it from excel) is as follows

If I do aggregation by weekly
           output in 1st  cell =  average prec from day 1 to 7 days.
            output in 2nd cell = average prec from 8 to 14 days.
            Output in 3rd cell=average prec from 15 to 21 day

If I do aggregation by 3 days
    output in 1st  cell =  average of day 1 to 3 days.
    output in 2nd cell = average of day 4 to 6 days.

I will provide the function  with "prec" and the "time step" input. I tried loops and `lubridate`, `POSIXct`, and some other functions, but I cant figure out the output like in third column.

One code I came up with ran without error but my output is bot correct. 
Where dat is my data set.

```
  tt=as.POSIXct(paste(dat$Date),format="%m/%d/%Y") #converting date formate 
     datZoo <- zoo(dat[,-c(1,3)], tt)
     weekly <- apply.weekly(datZoo,mean)
    prec_NLCD <-data.frame (weekly)
```

Also I wanted to write it in form of a function. Your suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end create the weekly means, `zm`, and then merge it with `z`.

(It would seem to make more sense to merge the means at the point that they are calculated, i.e. `merge(z, zm)` in place of the line marked ##, but for consistency with the output shown in the question they are put at the head of the data below.)

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

zm <- rollapplyr(z, 7, by = 7, mean)
merge(z, zm = zoo(coredata(zm), head(time(z), length(zm)))) ##
```

giving:

```
               z        zm
1950-01-01  3.11  4.081429
1950-01-02  3.25  9.642857
1950-01-03  4.81 11.517143
1950-01-04  7.07        NA
1950-01-05  4.25        NA
1950-01-06  3.11        NA
1950-01-07  2.97        NA
1950-01-08  2.83        NA
1950-01-09  2.72        NA
1950-01-10  2.72        NA
1950-01-11  2.60        NA
1950-01-12  2.83        NA
1950-01-13 17.00        NA
1950-01-14 36.80        NA
1950-01-15 42.40        NA
1950-01-16 17.00        NA
1950-01-17  7.07        NA
1950-01-18  3.96        NA
1950-01-19  3.54        NA
1950-01-20  3.40        NA
1950-01-21  3.25        NA
```

**Note:**

```
Lines <- "Date        Prec       
    1/1/1950    3.11E+00   
    1/2/1950    3.25E+00   
    1/3/1950    4.81E+00   
    1/4/1950    7.07E+00    
    1/5/1950    4.25E+00    
    1/6/1950    3.11E+00    
    1/7/1950    2.97E+00    
    1/8/1950    2.83E+00    
    1/9/1950    2.72E+00    
    1/10/1950   2.72E+00    
    1/11/1950   2.60E+00    
    1/12/1950   2.83E+00    
    1/13/1950   1.70E+01    
    1/14/1950   3.68E+01    
    1/15/1950   4.24E+01    
    1/16/1950   1.70E+01    
    1/17/1950   7.07E+00    
    1/18/1950   3.96E+00    
    1/19/1950   3.54E+00    
    1/20/1950   3.40E+00    
    1/21/1950   3.25E+00"
```